# How to identify color black in imager library in r

Tags: r, image, image-processing

I feel the answer to this questions should be straignt forward but I have spent hours on this and couldn't find an answer. So any help will be greatly appreciated.
I am using imager library in r to process an image. The image has some dark angles (4 corners are black) which I want to remove. So my code is this

```
remove_dark_edge<-function(img,w,h){
  while(sum(color.at(img,1,1)==c(1,1,1))==3 |
        sum(color.at(img,w,1)==c(1,1,1))==3 |
        sum(color.at(img,1,h)==c(1,1,1))==3 |
        sum(color.at(img,w,h)==c(1,1,1))==3 )
    {
    img=imsub(img,x>=2 & x<=w-2,y>=2 & y<=h-2)
    img=resize(img,w,h)
  }
  return(img)
}
```

I simply check 1 pixel at 4 corners and if the color is black then I crop the image and resize to the original size. 
This code works but the cropped image still has the dark corners.
So I did some quick check.
The header of my image looks like this

```
> head(as.data.frame(img.b,wide="c"))
  x y       c.1       c.2       c.3
1 1 1 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
2 2 1 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
3 3 1 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
4 4 1 0.9960784 0.9960784 0.9960784
5 5 1 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
6 6 1 0.9960784 0.9960784 0.9960784
```

and I plot some color

```
im <- as.cimg(c(25/255,25/255,25/255,25/255,25/255,25/255,25/255,25/255,25/255,25/255,25/255,25/255),x=2,y=2,cc=3)
im <- as.cimg(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),x=2,y=2,cc=3)
im <- as.cimg(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),x=2,y=2,cc=3)
plot(im)
```

All 1 gives me white color, while all 0 gives me black color.
However, all the 25/255 also gives me black (a little bit lighter but still quite black).
It seems that if RGB are same and the numerator is some small number I will get black but if I change any one value then the color totally changes.

So I am wondering what is the best rule to identify a black color?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a nebulous question. Black by definition is only R = G = B == 0. Any values above that are not black. If you're asking about human perception of black that's a different answer, and will often depend on contrast. An image patch with values of 25 next to a patch of values of 255 will look very black to the eye. A 25-valued patch next to a 0-valued patch will look much more gray to the eye. As such, there isn't really a "cutoff" of black vs. gray except at 0. If you're looking for more info, maybe you can expand on your question a little.

Comment: @malayka has a fair point. Maybe you can apply some pre-processing cutoff to your image before this step and set all values below x (25, for instance) to black. Then you can do your cropping procedure. If you're worried about the cutoff affecting the whole image, you can simply check the color on the modified image, but apply the crop to the non-modified version.